# DAX count of TransactionID's based on sum of value

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

[image]

In this table example, the DISTINCTCOUNT of TransactionID = 3 (basket count), however TransactionID 72461 has 3 x Unit sales (of different products) making it a multi-unit basket.   I am looking to iterate through the FACT table to only count multi-unit basket and not quite sure how to approach it

my attempt would be to create a VAR to sum(?) the units of distinct orders, then only count those TransactionID's with a value > 1, so in the table above the expected returned result would be 1.

```
SUMX(DISTINCT(FACT[TransactionID]), [Total Unit Sales]) 
RETURN
```

Core measure =

[Total Unit Sales] = SUM(UnitSales)

I'm not sure once i've created the SUMX of distinct Transactions ID's where to go.  Would i nest it in a logic statement?

Comment: Could you include markdown sample data, including your desired results please.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you wish to count the number of TransactionIDs which have more than one distinct Product:

```
MyMeasure =
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        'FACT',
        'FACT'[TransactionID],
        "Distinct Count of Products", DISTINCTCOUNT( 'FACT'[product] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX( MyTable, 0 + ( [Distinct Count of Products] > 1 ) )
```

Comment: seems it's better SUMMARIZE( ALL(FACT)...

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR TransactionIDValues=CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(FACT[TransactionID]),ALL(FACT))
VAR TransactionVSproducts= 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            TransactionIDValues
            ,"ProductCount",CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(FACT[product]))
        )    
RETURN
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            TransactionVSproducts
            ,[ProductCount]>1
        )
    )
```

Comment: Guess that should be more efficient since you're not using an iterator?

Comment: @JosWoolley yep, I tried to avoid it, but don't think it is a valuable difference with yours. And not sure at all that my measure is faster.